# why finite state machine cannot recognize a palindromic sequence

Tags: fsm, state-machine

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/223-finite-state-machines.html) to learn some knowledge on finite state machine.

It said that: ***It doesn’t take long to realise that a finite state machine cannot recognise a palindromic sequence.*** (in Grammar and machines section).

I googled a little bit the expression is true. But I don't know why. I think the diagram below could accept palindromic sequence, such as

ABA, (S1 --a--> S2 --b--> S1 --a--> S2)

AABAA, (S1 --a-- S2 --a--> S2 --b--> S1 --a--> S2 --a--> S2)

...

Where am I wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Your FSM seems to accept a lot of other strings, too. BBAA, for example.

Comment: Also, this seems to be more suited for Computer Science Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reasons for this may be like this

1. FSMs are not designed to remember large information. The states an FSM need to remember even a single alphabet in addition would be exponentially large.
2. Palindromic strings behave like a mirror. At one point the alphabet gets repeated based on a center.
   e.g: abcba -> center is c.
   FSMs cannot deterministically find this center point because they don't store additional information regarding to the center in a stack. (push down automata has this ability)
3. Suppose there is a mechanism to store the mid point. Even then FA struggles to backtrack through the previous states and figure out whether next alphabet after mid point matches with the previously entered alphabet before mid point. (Again without a stack to store previous inputs, this is difficult)

So it is unlikely an FA would recognize a palindrome

Now coming to your example,

An FA only accepts a language once it reaches an acceptable state at the last alphabet. Let's take AABAA for example. Four diagram to work wither S1 or S2 should be an accepting state. Let's say S2 is the accepting state and S1 is the initial state.

Then S1 --a-- S2 (1) --a-- S2 (2) --b-- S1 --a-- S2 (3) --a--S2 (4)

Since S2 is an accepting state, FA will accept the following strings

- (1) 'a'
- (2) 'aa'
- (3) 'aaba'
- (4) 'aabaa'

As you can see, even though it accepts a palindrome, it also accepts a bunch of other strings. The reason being, an FA cannot differentiate between before, and after a specific alphabet. It needs additional stack memory to handle these things (PA has this ability)